# React - Component not updating after props change

Tags: reactjs

I have a very simple react component to show FontAwesome Icons. It looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';

export default class FasIcon extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    console.log("rendering FasIcon ");
    const spanClass = ["icon is-", this.props.size, " is-", this.props.side].join("");

    let component = "";

    if (this.props.icon) {
      component = (
        <span className={spanClass}>
          <i className={["fas fa-", this.props.icon].join("")} />
        </span>
      );     
    }

    return component;
  }
}
```

I am using this on an email field that does email validation:

- Initially the prop `icon` is empty. This works.
- When starting to check if the address is used (an async server call) I update the icon to a value `spinner` and the icon displays correctly.
- When the check is completed i plan to change it to either `times` or `check`. This is correctly reflected in the props in the React Dev Tools, **but it is not reflected in the actual site.**

[image: Inconsestent Dev Tools / Props state]

**Update**

The issue was that I was importing the svg library which substituted the icon element for an svg. Once the SVG was placed, react was not able to substitute the icon in the DOM.

I've used the `fortawesome` prerelease plugins for react and it now works.

The render method was correctly called at all times.

Comment: usage looks correct, only thing I can see is that, it doesn't have to be a component and can just be a function. However that shouldn't be causing a problem. Which version of React are you using?

Comment: Where do you change the props?

Comment: 16.4.1 within Meteor. I made it a component to rule out this was the issue as well as because I wanted to add some further features later.

Comment: @MuratK I'm changing the props in the component where it is used. I initially thought there is a bug there, but given the component seems to have them updated correctly, I wonder what the reason is you are asking.

Comment: try ( https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate ) In your case, it is not re-rendering once it is rendered. with shouldcomponentupdate, you can render the view again if the props are different.

Comment: Thanks. I've added the solution. The component render method was called but the font awesome library was replacing any new icons' with an SVG so the react component lost control of the actual DOM element.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this you have to add a key prop to the i tag like this:

```
  <i key={this.props.icon} className={["fas fa-", this.props.icon].join("")} />
```